# Javascript: Auto Submit Form based on Value? (with short delay)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I would like to auto-submit a form on my page after a short delay based on a variable value (which is present in the URL string, as well as declared by another JS script). Not sure what the best practice way to do this would be?

MY PAGE URL:
http://www.domain.com/mypageaddress?var_1=value1&var_2=value2&**var_3=Returning%20Applicant**&var_4=value4

So when var_3=Returning%20Applicant , the form should submit without user input (and I would love a 1-second delay built in before that auto submit). Another script on the page also declares a JS variable for that same condition that might be easier to work with than the query string - JS var/value pair **returningapplicant=1** is the same as the URL string **var_3=Returning%20Applicant** that I'm trying to target. This is powered by a third party tool which I don't 100% understand, but they say that this JS variable can be referenced.

I would love some sample code that I could try for this function. Any help much appreciated and here's the extra info that will probably be needed for the JS script:

**FORM ACTION URL**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.tfaforms.com/responses/processor" class="hintsSide labelsLeftAligned" id="tfa_0">
```

**CURRENT FORM SUBMIT ELEMENT**

```
<div class="actions" id="tfa_0-A"><input type="submit" class="primaryAction" value="Next"></div>
```

Comment: Use a setInterval function which will check, at regular intervals, if your var is set at good value. If true, just call submit method of your form

Answer (score 2):

-in js

1. Wait for the window to load.

   document.onload = function() {}
2. Evaluate the url with the condition/s you describe. /
3. If the condition/s are met submit the form after waiting one second.

   ```
   if (window.location.href.match('var_3=Returning%20Applicant')) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           //submit form
           document.forms["your-form"].submit();
       },1000);
   }
   ```
4. Are you doing anything if something doesn't pass the conditions?

Your asking a whole bunch of stuff at once but that's the gist of what you're looking to do.  I'd probably parse the url params and evaluate them individually, validate the form, etc... if I were serious about this.  Hopefully this can get you started.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the clarifying question too. I should have clarified that if the var_3=Returning%20Applicant condition isn't met, nothing else needs to happen outside of "normal" functionality (basically allowing the user to fill in and submit the form themselves, instead of the delayed auto-submit if the condition is met).